# React, setState in componentDidMount doesn't always change the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm relatively new to React and I'm trying to change the value of one of my state properties at random once the page has rendered. But using `setState` in `componentDidMount` doesn't seem to work every time, sometimes I get the original state value returned (Which should never happen)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        houseAd: null
    };
}
```

and then to `setState`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const houseAds = ['ad1', 'ad2'];
    const rand = houseAds[Math.floor(Math.random() * houseAds.length)];

    this.setState({
        houseAd: rand
    });
}
```

Sometimes I get one or the other from my `houseAds` array, but sometimes it just returns `null`

Then in my render I'm just doing something simple like;

```
let ad;
if (this.state.houseAd === 'ad1') {
    ad = 'Ad1';
}
if (this.state.houseAd === 'ad2') {
    ad = 'Ad2'
}
```

But obviously when the state value is `null`, nothing shows up

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1575

Answer (score 1):

Code seems to be fine, only 1st time you will get `null` next time you will not get null values, check the state value using call back function after updating like this.

```
this.setState({
    houseAd: rand
}, ()=> {console.log(this.state.houseAd});
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is called **after** initial `render` - you probably didn't notice that - second render call is forced by `setState` quickly fixes/hides initial state.

`console.log(this.state.houseAd)` in `render` to proove that.

If you need sth at start - do it in `constructor`.